# Bash - Convert Single Column File into 5 Column Table

Tags: bash, awk

I need to convert 5 consecutive lines into columns so that I can perform sorting and comparison operations.  How would I transform the input file into a table of 5 columns and X rows?  AWK is most preferred :)

**Input File**

```
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_ATLNGAMQO1ZSADDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_ATLNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 1000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_MACNGAHRO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */
ALPSGA_MACNGA_0 {
    srlg-value 2000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-2-O1 */
ALPSGA_NSVNTN_0 {
    srlg-value 3000;
    srlg-cost 10000;
}
```

**Output File**

```
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_ATLNGAMQO1ZSADDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */   ALPSGA_ATLNGA_0 {       srlg-value 1000;        srlg-cost 10000;    }
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_MACNGAHRO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */   ALPSGA_MACNGA_0 {       srlg-value 2000;        srlg-cost 10000;    }
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-2-O1 */   ALPSGA_NSVNTN_0 {       srlg-value 3000;        srlg-cost 10000;    }
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: You should be able to `rs` (reshape) the lines as you want - but that's more a [su] answer than a [so] (programming) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="}\n";FS="\n";OFS=" "}{$1=$1;print}' file
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_ATLNGAMQO1ZSADDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */ ALPSGA_ATLNGA_0 {     srlg-value 1000;     srlg-cost 10000; }
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^3-A-2-O1_MACNGAHRO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1 */ ALPSGA_MACNGA_0 {     srlg-value 2000;     srlg-cost 10000; }
/* ALPSGAAKO1ZRDCDTNINF^1-A-1-O1_NSVNTNJYO1ZILADTNINF^2-A-2-O1 */ ALPSGA_NSVNTN_0 {     srlg-value 3000;     srlg-cost 10000; }
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    RS=ORS="}\n"  # set record separators appropriately
    FS="\n"       # field separator is a newline
    OFS=" "       # output field separator is a space
}
{
    $1=$1         # rebuild record
    print         # output
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straight-forward solution using AWK: For each line, read 4 more and print.

```
{
    printf "%s", $0  # Print the first line

    # Get the next 4 lines and print
    for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        getline
        printf " %s", $0
    }
    printf "\n"  # Finally, print a new line
}
```

## Discussion

- I used `printf`, which does not add a new line to the output
- After outputing the current line, I read the next 4 and print

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same too.

```
awk '{ORS=$0~/^}/?"\n":FS;print}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '{ORS=$0~/^}/?"\n":FS} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not seeing my first thought represented here, I feel I must contribute. (I like the approach of @james-brown, but I usually do not start with thinking about record and field separators.)

```
awk '{ emit=emit $0 " " } /^}$/ { print emit; emit="" }'
```

Basic approach: always append lines onto the `emit` variable, and emit and clear the `emit` variable when the last line so appended was a '}'.

This above will add a trailing space to its output, and its regular expression is coded to be very sensitive to that fifth line being only a single '}' character on a line.

Perhaps less clever; perhaps a bit more readable.